# Global Query Scope and Relationship with Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to get familiar with eloquent and I've been playing around with some global query scopes, but i'm not having much success when it comes to the effect that it has on relationships.

I have two models; product and category, each with some global query scopes added.

Products:

```
use productConditions;

protected $table = 'product';
public $timestamps = false;

private $websiteDetails;

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->websiteDetails = session('website');
}

public function scopeByCategory($query, $categoryId){
    return $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryId){
        $q->where('id', $categoryId);
    });
}

public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'product_category', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

category:

```
use categoryConditions;

protected $table = 'category';
public $timestamps = false;

public function products() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_category', 'category_id', 'product_id');
}
```

I'm using traits to boot the global scopes and the files are as follows:

So for products:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $builder->where('state', 'a');
    $builder->where('stock_level', '>', 0);
}

public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model){

    $query = $builder->getQuery();

    foreach((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where){

        if($where['column'] == 'state'){
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
        }

        if($where['column'] == 'stock_level'){
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
        }

    }
    $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
}
```

and for categories

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $websiteDetails = session('website');
    $builder->where('website_id', $websiteDetails['id']);
}

public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model){

    $query = $builder->getQuery();

    foreach((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where){

        if($where['column'] == 'website_id'){
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);
        }
    }
    $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
}
```

Because there are multiple records for the category field with a specific id, due to the face that there are multiple website profiles. I wanted to set a global query scope for categories -> website_id.

So this works beautifully when doing some like this:

```
$category = Category::with('products')->first();
$category->products;
```

It gets all the categories with the specified website_id and then pulls in the products.

However, it doesn't work, when I set up a query scope in the model, to do essentially the same thing, but the other way round. So, this doesn't work:

```
$category = Product::byCategory(2)->get();
```

Unless, I delete the global query scope in the category model and modify the whereHas closure to:

```
public function scopeByCategory($query, $categoryId){
    return $query->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($categoryId){
        $q->where('id', $categoryId)->where('website_id', $this->websiteDetails['id']);
    });
}
```

but doing it this way, means I can no longer query the Category model, without setting up some sort of byWebsite query scope method.

Could somebody tell me if I'm somehow doing it wrong, or suggest another solution to my problem.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try overwriting the query method in the category model, it should work for the categories.

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        $websiteDetails = session('website');
        return parent::newQuery()->where('website_id', $websiteDetails['id']);
    }
```

If it doesnt work as product relation try this:

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'product_category', 'product_id', 'category_id')
    ->where('website_id', $this->websiteDetails['id']);
    });
}
```